# Concatenate Bash commands in python

Tags: python, bash, shell

I want to concatenate several bash commands in a python file. Doing that for one command works:

```
import os
os.system('ls -l')
```

However if I dont know how to concatenate with another command like `pwd`

Answer (score 4):

Use && and so:

```
import os
os.system('ls -l && pwd')
```

This will execute pwd on the successful execution of "ls -l"

Answer (score 1):

Use a semicolon if you want to always execute command 2, regardless of whether or not command 1 ran successfully:

```
import os
os.system('ls -l; pwd')
```